# Setting up Raygun on a WCF REST Service

Tags: wcf, error-handling, raygun.io, raygun

I'm trying to set up [Raygun.io](https://raygun.io/) on a WCF service, and despite the simple instructions on the site, am having little luck getting things running.

I've signed up for my account, installed the `Mindscape.Raygun4Net` package via Nuget, then tried the following methods:

**Web.config approach:**
I added the config section, the Raygun section with my affiliate key, then added the module under `system.webserver`.  Nothing was logged.

**Global.asax approach:**
I tried adding a `RaygunClient` object to global.asax and then sending the exception on `Application_Error`.  Nothing was logged and the breakpoint inside `Application_Error` was never hit.

**IErrorHandler Approach:** This one actually got the errors logging to Raygun, but had its own issues:

**Error Handler**:

```
public class RaygunLogger : IErrorHandler
{
    private RaygunClient _client = new RaygunClient("5xqBOzTBrzIsS++3vsbFZw==");
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {

    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        _client.Send(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Behavior:**

```
public class RaygunServiceBahavior : IServiceBehavior
{

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = new RaygunLogger();

        foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {

    }
}
```

**Behavior Extension:**

```
public class RaygunBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(RaygunServiceBahavior); }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new RaygunServiceBahavior();
    }
}
```

The exception would be thrown, then the `Handle_Error` method would be called, sending the error to Raygun, but it always sends two exceptions instead of one.  The first exception is an `ObjectDisposedException: The message object has been disposed`.

Has anyone had luck setting up Raygun on WCF?  If so, do you have the same behavior or can you see anything I'm doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing something very similar and ended up with my IErrorHandler's HandleError() method re-entrant, originating from 
Mindscape.Raygun4Net.Builders.RaygunRequestMessageBuilder.GetIpAddress(HttpRequest request)

Rather than an object disposed exception it caused a System.Argument exception:

```
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.HandleErrorCommon(Exception error, ErrorHandlerFaultInfo&amp;amp; faultInfo)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.AddServerVariableToCollection(String name)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInServerVariablesCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.Get(String name)
   at Mindscape.Raygun4Net.Builders.RaygunRequestMessageBuilder.GetIpAddress(HttpRequest request)
```

I don't have a solution yet, however.

Comment: This was fixed in Raygun4Net version 4.2.1.  Putting a raygun hook in as posted above should work fine now.

This particular bug was reported here:
https://raygun.io/forums/thread/17338#17488

Another related exception was fixed in Raygun4net 5.0.1 as reported here:
https://raygun.io/forums/thread/19164#19781